# Track Email Open action in GA4

Tags: google-analytics-4

In Universal Analytics there's Email Tracking - Measurement Protocol for tracking email actions by embedding image pixel url in the email body. But not in the GA4 document.
Trying to achieve same with GA4 but looks like its not supported at this point. Is there any other alternative that I have missed to achieve the same with GA4?

Thanks in advance

Tried embedding image pixel url with UTM parameters, but that did not help.
Please let me know if there is any way to track email open action in GA4, other than google tag manager

Answer (score 3):

I have solved this as follows:

The IMG tag must point to your own server:

```
<img src="https://my.domain.com/email.php?subject=Test&template=mailTemplateSample" alt=" " />
```

There, a PHP receives the parameters and forwards them to the GA4 property via the measurement protocol:

```
<?php

// please edit ---------------------
$mid = "G-xxxxxxxxx";  // datastream measusrement id
$secret  = "xxxxxxxxx";  // measurement protocol api secret
$debug = 0;  // debug mode if required
// ---------------------------------


// read client id from ga cookie
if(isset($_COOKIE["_ga"])) {
  list(, , $id1, $id2) = explode(".", $_COOKIE["_ga"], 4);
  $client_id = "$id1.$id2";
} else {
  exit("client id undefined");
}

// read session id from ga session cookie
$ga4_session_cookie = "_ga_" . str_replace("G-", "", $mid);
if(isset($_COOKIE[$ga4_session_cookie])) {
  $cookie_parts = explode(".", $_COOKIE[$ga4_session_cookie]);
  $session_id = $cookie_parts[2];
}

// get url and parameters
$url = $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"];
parse_str($url, $params);
if (empty($params)) {
  exit("event parameters missing");
}

// create event parameters
$event_params = array();
foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
  $event_params[$key] = is_numeric($value) ? (int) $value : $value;
}
if(isset($session_id)) {
  $event_params['session_id'] = (int) $session_id;
  $event_params['engagement_time_msec'] = (int) 1000;
}
if($debug == 1) {
  $event_params['debug_mode'] = (int) 1;
}

// create payload
$data = array(
  "client_id" => $client_id,
  "non_personalized_ads" => false,
  "events" => array(
    array(
      "name" => "email_open",
      "params" => $event_params
    )
  )
);
$json = json_encode($data);

// define url with params
$url = "https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect?api_secret=".$secret."&measurement_id=".$mid;

// create HTTP header
$headers = array(
  "Content-Type: application/json"
);

// create HTTP request object
$options = array(
  "http" => array(
    "method" => "POST",
    "header" => implode("\r\n", $headers),
    "content" => $json
  )
);
$context = stream_context_create($options);

// send POST request
$response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

// debug output
if($debug == 1) {
  $file = fopen("email.json", "w");
  fwrite($file, $json);
  fclose($file);
  echo "$json";
}
?>
```

This creates a custom event called email_open if there is a GA cookie to read the client_id.